# I feel/It feels bad when I see people begging for food

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

1. I feel bad when I see people begging for food.
2. It feels bad when I see people begging for food.

1 seems pretty straight to me. It simply says how I personally feel. But what does 2 suggest? What does 'it' mean here?

Answer (score 1):

What the second sentence technically means is that "it feels bad to me when I see people begging for food". However, the reader can safely assume the sentence is talking about the feelings of a person so it can be shorthanded to just "it feels bad". "It" refers to seeing people beg for food. Therefore, the sentence in its full and technical sense would be "Seeing people beg for food feels bad to me when I see people beg for food".

That said, the first option is the one I'd go with also.

Comment: Is this sentence correct- "It felt so good when I saw my test results!"

Comment: @Ashraf It felt so good when I saw my test results. It felt great when I saw my test results. When I saw my test results, I felt amazing.

Comment: "When I saw my test results, I felt amazing." Isn't it more natural to say 'When I saw my test results, it felt amazing' instead of 'I felt amazing?' I've never heard 'I felt amazing.'

Comment: @Ashraf you can say both but you’re right “it felt amazing” is probably more common. But you can certainly say you felt amazing.